# IO Error when Uploading to Azure Blob Storage from Azure Web App

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, imageresizer, azure-blob-storage

After spending some hours searching for an answer, I've concluded that the question needs to be refocused on the Azure storage connection string

```
       <add key="yadayadayada_AzureStorageConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=yadayada;AccountKey=yoyoyoyo==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net" />
```

and the use of ImageResizer and AzureReader2 which also has a connection string. The settings for that are:

```
     <resizer>
<pipeline defaultCommands="autorotate.default=true" />
<plugins>
  <add name="AzureReader2" connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=accountname;AccountKey=acctkey==" endpoint="http://acctnumber.blob.core.windows.net/" prefix="~/azure" />
</plugins>
```

As I change the endpoints, I get different errors. When I change the azure prefix to "~/" it crashes.

Here is the original question, but I'm asking with more certainty what should the storage connection strings be to authorize upload to my azure website.

Here's the original question: Uploading from my development machine to Azure blob storage works fine. However, uploading from the deployed (on Azure) asp.net mvc app gets this error: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'D:\Windows\system32\ 
Do I need to establish write permission for the app, and if so how?

Or is there something wrong with my code?

```
  private CloudBlobContainer GetCloudBlobContainer()
    {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
                CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("accountidhere_AzureStorageConnectionString"));
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("FOLDER NAME HERE");
        return container;
    }


  public async Task<ActionResult> AddAnnouncementPhotos(AddPhotosViewModel vm, FormCollection fcoll)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)

        {
            int theID = vm.ThePost.PostId;

            foreach (string fileName in Request.Files)
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase fb = Request.Files[fileName];

                string caption = fileName.Replace("File", "Photo");
                var phostring = caption + ".PhotoCaption";

                if (fb != null && fb.ContentLength > 0 && fb.ContentType.StartsWith("image"))
                {
                    string path = fb.FileName;

                    string ext = path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf("."));
                    string newname = Guid.NewGuid() + ext;

                    CloudBlobContainer container = GetCloudBlobContainer();

                    CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(newname);
                    blob.Properties.ContentType = fb.ContentType;

                    using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(path))
                    {
                        blob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
                    }
```

Adding the Stack Trace:

```
        FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'D:\Windows\system32\DSC02724.JPG'.]
   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) +519
   System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost) +829
   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share) +65
   swIndWorkshop.Controllers.<AddAnnouncementPhotos>d__14.MoveNext() in C:\Users\JHstandard\Documents\aspnetProjects\swIndWorkshop\swIndWorkshop\Controllers\AnnouncementsController.cs:420
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +61
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +17
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__11_0() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_1.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__2() +228
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.<BeginInvokeAction>b__3() +35
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +11
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecute>b__151_2(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +577
   System.Web.<>c__DisplayClass285_0.<ExecuteStepImpl>b__0() +24
   System.Web.StepInvoker.Invoke(Action executionStep) +100
   System.Web.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Invoke>b__0() +17
   Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule.OnExecuteRequestStep(HttpContextBase context, Action step) +64
   System.Web.<>c__DisplayClass284_0.<OnExecuteRequestStep>b__0(Action nextStepAction) +54
   System.Web.StepInvoker.Invoke(Action executionStep) +84
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +100
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +163
```

Comment: Where is the Stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify the whole path used in `var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(path)`, so it's current directory by default.

On Azure the process current working directory is `D:\Windows\system32\`, where we have no access to write and the uploaded file can't be there either.

**Update**

1. Recommand to use InputStream, so we don't have to save file on web server.

   Just replace `System.IO.File.OpenRead(path)` with `fb.InputStream`.
2. To use `System.IO.File.OpenRead(path)`, need some modification in your if segment.

   ```
   if (fb != null && fb.ContentLength > 0 && fb.ContentType.StartsWith("image"))
   {
       string path = fb.FileName;
       // add these two line to save file on web app server
       var wholePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/"), path);
       fb.SaveAs(wholePath);
       .....
       using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(wholePath))
       {
           blob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
       }
       ....
   }
   ```

Comment: I'm uploading to blob storage, though, not to a folder within my app.

Comment: @JaneH Yes, I mean your file is uploaded to web app through http request first. Then you use `UploadFromStream` to upload it to Azure Storage, am I right?

Comment: I don't believe so. I've never seen that in any of the documents.

Comment: @JaneH Let me explain, your method [System.IO.File.OpenRead(path)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.openread?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_IO_File_OpenRead_System_String_) is to read a file on the system, which means your file is physically on the server your web app is deployed. If you check locally, you can find your file is also somewhere in your web app folder.

Comment: @JaneH Really sorry for my mistake, I thought `Uploading from my development machine to Azure blob storage works` means you ran a web app locally and uploading works, so I thought you have set to save file on web app folder. Forgive me for the waste of your time, have updated my answer, see whether it's useful and feel free to ask me if you meet problems.

Comment: No problem, @Jerry Liu. I have had storage accounts that worked that way, although it is possible to find a stream upload that will go direct to the storage. Thanks for putting thought into it.

Comment: @JaneH Great, if my suggestion did some help, could you accept it as an answer, or you can just post your solution so that other can refer to.

Comment: Unfortunately, @Jerry Liu, there is no solution yet. I believe the answer is the proper connection string and really hope someone will provide it.